# Help binding my silverlight datagrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

[image]

I have an entity called Incident, as you can see on the picture, it holds a list with several bugs.

Then I have a datagrid that I connect a list with all my incident to:

```
        List<ExtendedIncident> allIncidents;
                myGrid.ItemsSource = allIncidents;
```

Now I bind some of the values from every incident, like this in the xaml code:

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="grid" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="grid_SelectionChanged">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Incident">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding CallId}" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"></HyperlinkButton>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Beskrivnig" Binding="{Binding Description}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Beskrivnig" Binding="{Binding Status}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
```

My problem now is that I would like to add some columns that presents some data from the bugs, that are relevant (stored in the list for the incident) in the same row. How can I present data from the list of buggs from the incident?

Would be very thankful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RowDetailsTemplate:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Height="400" IsReadOnly="True" >
    <sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding BuggItems}/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Or alternatively a property that aggregates all the items stored in list (below an example if IDs are strings).

```
public partial class Incident
{
   public string IDs
    {
        get
        {
            return BuggItems.Aggregate((a,b) => a + "," + b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the tip with RowDetailsTemplate, that really helps, since alot of incidents have alot of buggs connected to them, so that would be great. Regarding the other problem, is that the incident hols a list with bug entities, that has alot of other values, so the question would be how I should extract that data. I would like to do something like:  <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Beskrivnig" Binding="{Binding foreach(bugitem.bugid in buglist)}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>

Comment: I think the solution to the problem then is to insert another datagrid inside the RowDetailsTemplate that is binded to BuggItems. Or, alternatively, if you don't want the data to be shown in rows you could aggregate the IDs in another property in a partial class and bind a new column to it.